# cx_Freeze python exe conversion no modual named "re"

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I am trying to convert a python script into an exe using cx_Freeze, but after converting it and trying to run it, it comes up with the erre "no modual named "re"". Im not sure what that is, but I dont reference it in my code at all. Here is a link to my code and the setup script:

setup: http://pastebin.com/6JN093u7

My code: http://pastebin.com/nEinps53

Im using Python 3.3 on win7, though my code was written in 3.2, if that makes a difference. If I can supply any more information then please ask.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does your code normally compile on its own (before you run it through cx_Freeze)? "re" is the python regular expression library.
2. If you are making this for a client, are you sure your contract allows you to publicly post the source code in its entirety like this?
3. No offense, but your coding style is really bad. You repeat a lot of code: you could simplify this program a lot by writing generalized functions. For instance, lines 16-60 could be simplified to this:

   ```
   def get_user_response(text, err_text="Please enter a number"):
       derp=False
       while derp == False:
           try:
               val = str(input(text))
               derp = True
            except ValueError:
                   win32api.MessageBox(None,err_text, "Error!")
                   derp = False
           derp = False
       return val
   room_price.write(get_user_response("What is the room price?"))
   night_price.write(get_user_response("What is the laundry price?"))
   Laundry_price.write(get_user_response("What is the internet price per hour?"))
   Telephone_price.write(get_user_response("What is the telephone price per hour?"))
   ```
4. On that note: consider the last 4 lines: you use lower case for the first two variable names and mixed case for the second two variables. Why? This is just going to make your life hard. You should pick a naming convention and stick with it.
5. Your `PassworD()` function is just a really, really bad idea. Don't store passwords in plain text. A common solution is to store passwords as salted-hashes, but I'm not going to pretend to be awesome at encryption or security. But I know that what you are doing is a bad idea and you should research alternative solutions to storing passwords in plaintext.

In any event: I don't see the source of your particular error. Sorry, you'll have to figure that out for yourself. But you could greatly simplify your code in various ways (not the least of which would be compartmentalizing frequently repeated code and using naming conventions), and simpler code is much easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware that my code is bad, but this is for a school project (secondary school) and to be honest is my first thing I have made over 50 lines. Im sure there are many things I can do to greatly improve it, but as there is a deadline I haven't had much time. Not to mention I am new to writing code, I know I have much to learn. As for the password function, this isnt really intended for real life use, so as long as it can store a password its fine. I have some basic idea on how to make it actually secure. Anyway, im using portable Python so it dosnt get compiled.

Comment: by "compile" I mean can you run the code normally in the interpreter without receiving errors.